# How to return the state of method that modify many items?

Tags: c#, exception

I have a method that update many items. Because of concurrency, some items could be update correctly, another can't update because user send incorrect data and anothers can't be update because another process could delete the item that user wants to update.

So I was thinking how give information to the consumer of the library which items could be updated, which items has errors and which items couldn't be update because they are deleted.

I was  thinking a method something like that, but I have the feel that it is a bit smelly code.

```
public List<TypeItems> UpdateItems(IEnumerable<MyType> paramItems)
{
    List<MyTyme> myLstCorrectItems = new List<MyType>();
    List<Exception> myLstExceptions = new List<Exception>();

    foreach (MyTime item in paramItems)
    {
        try
        {
            Item.Update(newValue);
            myLstCorrectItems.Add(item);
        }
        catch (System.Exception)
        {
            Exception myException = new Exception("ERROR " + item.ID + ex.Message);
            myLstExceptions.Add(myException);
        }
    }


    if(myLstExceptions.Count == 0)
    {
        return myLstCorrectItems;
    }



    foreach(MyType iterator in myLstCorrectItems)
    {
        Exception myException = new Exception("OK " + iterator.ID);
        myLstExceptions.Add(myException);
    }


    throw new AggregateException("ERRORS", myLstExceptions);
}
```

The idea of the code is that if there is no items with exceptions, return the list of all the items that are updated. When the consumer receive the list, it can compare if some item is not in the list, it means it was deleted and can warning to the user. If the item exists, it has the new values because of the update.

If there is at least one item with errors, I create an aggregate exception in which I add all the exceptions. Also, I create a "fake expcetion" for the correct items, so the consumer would receive all the processed items. So if some item is not in the agreegate exception, it can know that was deleted from another process.

Perhaps it would be better to use a custom exception, to avoid to parse the string of the error, to see if it is OK or ERROR, but this is not my doubt.

My doubt it is to know if it is the general idea is good or not, to use a "fake expcetion" to include the correct items.

But if there is a better or alternative ways to notify the final result of each item, I would be good to can know  them.

Thanks.

EDIT: Solution 1: return correct and incorrect items:

```
public (List<MyType> CorrectItems, List<MyType> IncorrectItems) UpdateItems(IEnumerable<MyType> paramItems)
{
    List<MyTyme> myLstCorrectItems = new List<MyType>();
    List<Mytype> myLstIncorrectItems = new List<Mytype>();

    foreach (MyTime item in paramItems)
    {
        try
        {
            Item.Update(newValue);
            myLstCorrectItems.Add(item);
        }
        catch (System.Exception)
        {
            myLstIncorrectItems.Add(item);
        }
    }


    return (myLstCorrectItems, myLstIncorrectItems);
}
```

Comment: That's a weird design. Hard to understand and to use. Why can't you just return two lists and be done with?

Comment: It *might* be a good thing to throw an exception in case of errors within the items, when these errors are **unexepcted**. What definitly is **not** a good idea is to throw an exception in case of everything working correctly.

Comment: @freakish I have read that if  there is errors, it is better to throw and exception than return a value that is a code that consumer has to check. But I considerated to return a tuple with two list, for correct and incorrect items.

Comment: @HimBromBeere If all it is correct, I return a list with all the items. I only throw an exception if at least one is incorrect. But I am agree that really is not an elegant solution.

Comment: I suggest reading this post from Eric Lippert regarding exceptions and when to throw them and when not: https://ericlippert.com/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/

Comment: @ÁlvaroGarcía while it is a matter of opinion, I strongly believe that expected errors are not exceptional, and therefore you should not use exceptions for them. In fact exceptions are abused heavily for logic flow nowadays, which I hate. And this is precisely your case. Moreover you cannot at the same time return correct results and throw an exception for failures. You do return in the 100% correct path. So it is only natural to always return both correct results and failures. The design you have, to (at least partially) return correct results via exceptions, is awkward.

Comment: @freakish I have edit the original return two lists. Would it be the correct way to do it? I mean that in the catch, just I add the incorrect item to the list.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGarcía looks fine to me. I personally would keep a pair (Item, Exception) in the second list. Or some other way to indicate what exactly went wrong.

Comment: @freakish Thanks for you comments. One related question. If I check a parameter and I see it is incorrect because it is lower than 0 for example and it is not correct. would you throw and exception or return a value because you considerate it an expected error?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGarcía depends. Nowadays I feel like returning errors by value is almost always a correct approach (and is universal, there are modern languages that don't support exceptions, e.g. Rust). The problem with that approach is that this requires the caller to check for errors and react appropriately. And so returning errors by value is IMO better, but requires discipline from devs. If you are working with less experienced devs, then I would go with exceptions. Please remember that this is only my opinion, and I don't think there is one correct way here.

Comment: @freakish Thanks. I know that there are many ways, but really it is good to have different points of view, or ways to do.

Answer (score 2):

It is a bad idea, to create these fake exceptions to mark the correct items. This is very confusing and I certainly would not expect it. Another solution is to create your own type for the result:

```
public UpdateItemsResult UpdateItems(IEnumerable<MyType> paramItems)
{
   // ...
}
```

Your type might look like this:

```
public class UpdateItemsResult
{
   public List<int> IdsOfUpdatedItems {get;set;}

   public List<int> IdsOfFailedItems {get;set;}
}
```

The first list contains the ids of the items, at which the update worked. The second list contains the ids of items, at which some error occurred. Of couse, you can adapt the type to your needs.

Comment: Yes, I considerated to return a tuple with 2 items, one for the correct items and another for the incorrect, instead of create a class for that, but the idea is the same.